# L2S association property (IEnumerable) in Model being cleared from one call of RenderAction to next

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I have a model which looks like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<AnotherClass> Foo { get; set; }
    // other properties go here
}
```

Then a view which does something like this:

```
@model Asdf.MyModel

@{ Html.RenderAction("Partial", Model); } <!-- asdf: Model.Foo.Count == 3 -->
@{ Html.RenderAction("Partial", Model); } <!-- qwer: Model.Foo.Count == 0 -->
```

A controller with something like this in it:

```
public ActionResult Partial(MyModel model)
{
    //do some things

    return this.View(model);
}
```

`Partial.cshtml` doesn't have anything special in it

When I run, `Model.Foo` has say 3 items in it. First it hits the point marked `asdf` and has the 3 items. When it gets to the next line (`qwer`) `Foo` is empty! Other properties of `Model` are still there though.

Any ideas why this would happen and how to resolve?

---

**UPDATE**

The `IEnumerable` is a Linq-to-SQL association property. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: instead of Html.RenderAction use Html.RenderPartial/  Html.Partial

Comment: @swapneel I can't use `RenderPartial` as that only calls the View and not the Controller.

Comment: In the `//do some things` section of your Partial controller action maybe you are doing some things that you shouldn't be doing or which would explain the behavior you are observing :-) What happened when you removed everything from this action and left only the `return View(model);` in it? Are you still observing the same behavior?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I took out all things which query the `model` and still the same occurs. :(

Comment: Take out _everything_

Comment: @JohnSaunders Taking out everything (except the `return View(...)`) still results in the same issue.